# How do I use cdemu with Unity?

Tags: unity, systray

There is this great application that can mount various CD images and thus emulate a CD drive. However, it is based on tray so it does not play nice with Unity. How can it be run in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run this command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "$(gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist | sed -e "s:\[:\['gcdemu' ,:")"
```

which will add cdemu application to Unity panel whitelist.