# Mount an ISO image in Wine?

Tags: wine, mount, iso

I need to install some program in wine, which require to access a mounted ISO image. Whenever I mount an ISO image in Nautilus, in which drive it mounted in Wine?

For some programs which can find the ISO automatically, I have no problem.

Comment: ***Important note:*** `WINEPREFIX=/home/<user>/pathToApplication/ winetricks` will run winetricks *on* your *specific wine prefix*! It's very important that you use the right prefix, or your `winecfg` etc. won't be applied to the application you're trying to fix!

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/55279/462615

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### [CDemu](http://cdemu.sourceforge.net/)

We sucessfully mounted CD or DVD images for application installation in Wine or for running an application which needs access to its CD using **CDemu**. Amongst ISO a wide variety of other formats are supported. Therefore the image does not need to be in ISO format.

The application can be installed by [adding the following ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) to our sources:

- **ppa:cdemu/ppa**

We can then install the CDemu client and the CDemu daemon with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cdemu-daemon cdemu-client
```

After logging out and back in, or a reboot, the daemon will be started. To mount an ISO file as CD we can then issue:

```
cdemu load <number> <path_to_iso>
```

The `<number>` corresponds to the internal number of drives loaded by CDemu (per default 2 drives, change this in `/etc/default/cdemu-daemon` to a higher number if needed.

The following is an example command to load a drive `0` from an `image.iso`:

```
cdemu load 0 /home/nur/images/image.iso
```

This will unload an image:

```
cdemu unload <number>
```

Related questions:

- [How do I use cdemu with Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98116/how-do-i-use-cdemu-with-unity)
- [Apps capable of mounting/unmounting CD/DVD Images with multi-sector or protected format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76346/apps-capable-of-mounting-unmounting-cd-dvd-images-with-multi-sector-or-protected)
- [How can I graphically mount ISOs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43469/how-can-i-graphically-mount-isos)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just discovered this amazing program ! Worked well for my two disc game installation, whilst the other one don't. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

After you mount the ISO or the disk with any tools or commands which you prefer, start **Configure Wine** create a new Drive mapping. Click Add, browse the path and select OK. Here, I've mapped Ubuntu 13.10 i386 DVD to drive letter `e:` in wine (`g:` is for my Flash Drive).

[image: cinfigWine]

Then you can browse the iso or disk in the `$HOME/user/.wine`'s `dosdrives` directory.

[image: dosdevices]

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo mount -o loop /path/to.iso /mnt/cdrom/
```

Comment: Actually, the user seems have already mounted the ISO. But he looks for a way to map already mounted images into Wine devices automatically.

Comment: Nur mounted an image using Nautilus, that is why wine can not see it. If mount the image to usual cdrom location then wine able to see it.

Comment: In late Ubuntu releases, CD's  mounted in the new mounting path: /media/user_name/cd_title. Wine does not create mapping automatically for it otherwise.

Comment: Your solution works well. I would suggest to add a permanent mapping for `/mnt/cdrom/` using `winecfg`/Wine Configuration in drives tab or create a link to. `ln -s /mnt/cdrom /home/user_name/.wine/dosdevices/e:`

Answer (score 3):

If you have mounted an .iso image in Ubuntu, Wine will treat it exactly as Ubuntu is treating it. So if you navigate to / with a Wine program (I think it is the Z:\ folder), you will see all of your Ubuntu files and folders, and you can navigate to the mount point of the iso, which will be listed with the `mount` command in the terminal (it's probably somewhere in /mount)

Comment: programs like Rebirth won't consider that the CD-Rom is available

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mount iso in Ubuntu, however want to mount iso in Wine only.

Right click on iso file, select `Open With` -> `Archive Manager`. Unpack iso content into new folder e.g. `iso`.
[image]

In Wine go to `Configure Wine` select `Drivers` tab. Click `Add...` to add new driver, select any letter. Select already created driver, click `Browse...` and specify extracted `iso` folder path.

[image]

[image]

Next open `Control panel` select `Add/Remove Programs` click `Install...` specify some `.exe` file from mounted drive.

[image]