# Trying to run a Windows98/ME/2000/XP game through Wine

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I have been trying to install a game called "Tortuga, Pirates of the New World'. I tried through the usual pressing-on-the-AutoRun-and-going-onfrom-there which opens the installer page and gives me an error saying

```
Error: This program will not run on Windows32s.
```

I then explored the disk further and came across the Tortuga.exe but when I clicked on that another error came up saying:

```
Please insert a disk into your CD/DVD drive and restart the application
```

But, naturally, the disk is already there.

I then tried PlayOnLinux, but it gave me the same errors, even after I found the game on the WineHQ database (it's a bronze game) and the tester said that they used Wine 1.6. I downloaded Wine 1.6 through PlayOnLinux, chose it as the Wine program to run the game on and it still told me that it crashed.

The link below is the Wine page where it details that it runs but it has a workaround as it does not install:
[wine Tortuga page](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=29264)

If I could perhaps have some help working out what to do for the workaround I could get it working?

I am very new and rather nervous when working through terminal, but if going through there might get it working I'm willing to try, and the reason why I say this is that there is some sort of patch on the Wine page, but I don't know where to type it.

Comment: Issues like yours are expected from running software designed for another OS. We're lucky we can at least run some but if we don't then blame the makers of that software. I made a good experience with [CDemu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278912/mount-an-iso-image-in-wine) for mounting CD images to Wine. A "Bronze" rating for Wine is close to Garbage and indicates that there will not be much fun.

Comment: Why was this closed as a dupe?  It asked specifically about a certain game, not just Windows software in general.

Comment: As a general rule-of-thumb with Wine, your best bet for getting a piece of software running is installing the latest Wine Staging from here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu